# Multiple MS SQL databases as one datasource

Tags: sql-server, business-intelligence

I have multiple databases which are identical comparing by tables, but has different data. lets say each database per user. i need to use the all as one data source in some kind of business intelligence tool.
any suggestions about using databases as one? BI tool should be free.

Answer (score -1):

Create a DataMart and drag the data from each source into the 'Mart and use your tool against that DB.